Cómo puedo empezar a aprender sobre seguridad informática(¿Alguna página?)
Quiero empezar a saber sobre seguridad informatica por qué me da curiosidad y quiero aprender¿Me recomiendan alguna página?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Sin saber tus conocimientos (programación, protocolos web, etc) ni experiencia no podemos aconsejarte nada.
